# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.in C#?

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, push-notification

my code for gcm:

```
  [WebMethod]
        public void SendNotificationToAndroid()
        {
            string DeviceTokenID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
           // string deviceId = notificationId;
            const string tickerText = "Text";
            const string contentTitle = "Title";
            string message = "Hello world";
            string postData =
            "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + DeviceTokenID + "\" ], " +
              "\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"" + tickerText + "\", " +
                         "\"contentTitle\":\"" + contentTitle + "\", " +
                         "\"message\": \"" + message + "\"}}";
            SendGcmNotification("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", postData, "application/json");
        }




private void SendGcmNotification(string apiKey, string postData, string postDataContentType)
        {
            //  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateServerCertificate;
            var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
            request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;


            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;  

            var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();



            try
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse();
                var responseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
                if (responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
                {
                    const string text = "Unauthorized - need new token";
                    Context.Response.Write(text);
                }
                else if (!responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
                {
                    const string text = "Response from web service isn't OK";
                    Context.Response.Write(text);
                }
                // ReSharper disable AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                // ReSharper restore AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
                reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                //Context.Response.Write();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Context.Response.Write(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

this is my push notification code at server side.The response  i am getting error "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
 please any one one help.  Thank yOu in advance.

Comment: please any one reply me

Comment: try by adding this..request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

request.PreAuthenticate = true;

request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Answer (score 0):

Try unsing session on your web method

```
 [WebMethod(true)]
```